# How to use two recyclerview (one in vertical and the other in horizontal)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txgqj.jpg)

As on the attached image, I wish to realize this design.
In a CoordinatorLayout, there is the AppBarLayout that contains an image and in the bottom life I want to insert two RecyclerViews, one vertical (the first) and the other horizontal (the second down)

Comment: Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523216/4978313

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `RecyclerView`, you need to specify a `LayoutManager` that is responsible for laying out each item in the view. The `LinearLayoutManager` allows you to specify an orientation, just like a normal `LinearLayout` would.

For vertical recycler view you can use

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

To create a horizontal list with `RecyclerView`, you have to use this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```